# How to perform operations on timezone specific data when your server is in a different timezone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, datetime, momentjs

I'm having trouble understanding how servers handle timezone specific operations and present local information to users. I've read that you should never need to store a users local timezone, but instead just store the date in a UTC offset timestamp.

So take for example I have a user that's located in California but my server is located in New York. I build a calendar app that needs to display all the appointments that this person has for today from midnight to midnight inclusive. I query the database for all my appointments and the server generates 2 dates like this:

```
let date_1 = moment().startOf('day').utc();
let date_2 = moment().endOf('day').utc();
```

The issue is of course that both `date_1` and `date_2` are first generated based on New York time which is 4 hours ahead of California so even if I run a query like:
`SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE somedate BETWEEN date_1 AND date_2;`
 I'll end up with data that is still not what the user is asking for.

Don't I have to know the timezone of the person or should I build the api in a way that the front end can't simply ask for data but must provide 2 dates? Is it wrong for the server to try to calculate what days the user is asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **timestamp** value to store in Database.  [Get current timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/).
As the timestamp value is always unique and common, so in order to get the right time zone, you need to handle it on the frontend,

```
Date.now()
>> 1539606894329
new Date(1539606894329)
>> Mon Oct 15 2018 18:04:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

[Conversion of the same timestamp for different timezone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNmlu.png)